Olympiad Question. Prove that 2 disjoint subsets of $S$ with $|A| = |B|$ such that $2$ sums, $x$ and $y$, differ less by $0.01$, $|x − y| < 1/100$.

Let $S$ be a set of $10$ positive integers. Prove that one can find two disjoint
subsets $A = {a_1, . . . , a_k}$ and B = ${b_1, . . . , b_k}$ of $S$ with $|A| = |B|$ such that the sums
$x = 1/a_1 + · · · + 1/a_k$ and $y = 1/b_1 + · · · + 1/b_k$
differ by less than $0.01$; i.e., $|x − y| < 1/100$.

My thoughts:
Partition the interval $(0.00, 2.50]$ into $250$ intervals each of size $0.01$.
$(0.00, 2.50] = (0.00, 0.01] ∪ (0.01, 0.02] ∪ (0.02, 0.03] ∪ · · · ∪ (2.49, 2.50].$
Now consider all possible sets,$S$, we can choose from the given $10$ positive integers with
$|S| = 5$. Because each of the positive integers must be different, the smallest possible
reciprocal sum of one of these sets is $1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5<2.5$
Therefore each of these different sets has a reciprocal sum lying somewhere in the interval
$(0.00, 2.50)$. The number of such sets $S$ is $10C5 = 252$ but the number of intervals in
our partition is only $250$, so I want to use the Pigeonhole Principle, however I am stuck at this step.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

(Correct me if I'm wrong) It seems to me that you have 252 pigeons (These sets of $|S| = 5$) and 250 holes (the intervals of size 0.01), so you can apply PGH to conclude that there is (at least) one hole with (at least) 2 pigeons. Remove any common terms.    $\quad$ In fact, if you just take all $2^{10} - 1 > 1000$ subsets with value of $ \sum 1/i < 3$, then we have two sets whose values that are within 0.003 of each other.
